# Circumcenter coordinates for a isosceles triangle

Tags: math, graphics, geometry

I need to calculate **circumcenter coordinates** (or at least I hope they're called that) at point **C** for an  **isosceles** triangle (the circle must be such, that created triangle is). I know the point **O** (origin), two vectors **p** and **q** (length may differ) originating in that point (leading to points **P** and **Q**). I also know the radius **r** of this to be circumscribed circle. When the circle's center is known it should create said green highlighted isosceles triangle. Here is drawing for better understanding:

[image]

**Update (solution):**

1. Calculates the length of **p** and **q** vectors

   [image]

   [image]
2. Normalize them both, and add them together

   [image]
3. Normalize this to be **OC** vector again

   [image]

   [image]
4. Finally extend **OC** vector from point of origin **O** to length equivalent to radius **r**

   [image]

Comment: You should try MathOverflow ...

Comment: I've said it already, I did yesterday, but 2D graphics is quite confusing to pure mathematicians over there. Also the tags are not quite good there (I'd expect more large set of mathematical jargon, vector for example).

Comment: OK, I'm moving it to Math, I guess yet another round of why is y-axis up negative.

Comment: This question belongs on another site (maybe), namely Math Stack Exchange, but it belongs here as well. Still waiting for Programming-Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: I think you are getting hooked on someone else doing your work for you.

Comment: Wrong. First, this is my side project. I love programming and solving math, and before I even post it here, I'm trying to solve the problem myself. Sometimes I've to admit defeat. But I'm keeping large project in my mind (and cannot stray too much), and it is tough for me to recall the bits of math I remember (not actually that little). It is unreasonable for me to spend days figuring it out, in a scope of the project, that should take months. You see only the iceberg of what I'm asking, but you obviously don't see the big picture, and countless solutions I did on my own.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481580/circumcenter-coordinates-for-a-isosceles-triangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking geometrically:

1. normalise vectors `p` and `q`, i.e. `p = p / |p|`, `q = q / |q|`
2. add them together
3. normalise the result
4. multiply that by `r` - this is the vector `OC`
5. add to `O`

Steps 1 - 3 simply produce the bisection of the vectors `p` and `q`

**EDIT** this is simplified somewhat compared to my original answer.

Comment: OK, I'm checking the Save's at the moment. If you could cook up an equation it would be a bliss, believe me, I'd more than my share today. :D

Comment: there's no single equation, but if you follow the steps above you should get to the right place.  For simplicity, ignore `O` until the very end, as you already know the vectors `p` and `q`.  You can then just treat (0, 0) as the origin and add it back to `C` once you've done the rotation.

Comment: So should I do acos to get the angle? I'm quite burnt out for today (and not that good in math anyway), so excuse probable silly questions like that.

Comment: @SmartK8 actually, I've updated this to use no trig at all.  Please look again.

Comment: Yep, that I understand. Damn, so simple in the end. Let me verify that.

Comment: @SmartK8 remember that when he says add the together, he means the [vector sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorAddition.html), not the algebric one

Comment: I know, I'm quite tired, I've solved like 50 of these problems today. One you've assisted me with Save. I'm working on a quite complicated problem, but now I'm burnt out. It's almost midnight here in Europe. My brain's crisp.

Comment: So I've calculated it manually, and it works (it returned [48.4046, 56.8784] for the situation given below), thanks. But those normalizations are quite expensive (square roots). Can you put (under the line somewhere), the original solution with dot product? It might be faster, I didn't caught how many trig. operations, or otherwise would be needed, but still. Or if you see immediately that the original solution was slower, just tell me so.

Comment: the previous version using trig would be slower than this version using square roots.  You should only need three sqrt ops in total, whereas the previous would still have needed at least two of those, plus an `acos` and a few `sin` and `cos` ops too.

Comment: OK, in that case thanks. Just for the laughs, they've solved it on the Math forum as well (I was in the processes of moving/closing this question). But I like your answer better, more programmy: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481580/circumcenter-coordinates-for-a-isosceles-triangle

Comment: @SmartK8 Yes, the answer there is equivalent to mine here.

Answer (score 1):

The first equation of your system is:

```
(x_c-x_o)^2 + (y_c-y_o)^2 = r^2
```

The second one is more convoluted. You must intersect the circumference

```
(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2 = r^2
```

with your two vectors, that have equation rispectively

```
y = (Q_y/Q_x)*x and y = (P_y/P_x)*x
```

this gives you the two points of intersection p and q in function of x_c and y_c. Now force hte distance OP and OQ to be equal (you want an isoscele triangle), and you have your second equation.
Solve hte two equation system and you have the formula for x_c and y_c.

Assuming i did the math right, the solution is:

```
x_c = ((a+b)^2 * r^2) / ((a+b)^2+4)
y_c = (-2*(a+b) * r^2) / ((a+b)^2+4)
```

where

```
a = p_y / p_x
b = q_y / q_x
```

Comment: Hi again, give me a sec, to verify it. :)

Comment: If the resul it's wrong i'll write down the steps to obtain it, so that you can eventually fix the calculations ( that are quite a lot in the approach i followed). By the way, you can get 2 solutions since since you can prolongue the two vector the other way and get a symmetric one

Comment: Please do, I've tried it and for O [22, 18], P [39, 153], Q [122, 73] and r = 47 it returns x_c = ~1881. :D

Comment: [Edit: I've miscalculated it's 816, but still off)]

Comment: x and y, are coordinates of the O?

Comment: I've wrote the sketch of how you can get the two coordinates in function of Q, P and R

Comment: Oh god ... the whole time I assumed O was the origin, aka (0,0). I'd use my formulas to find x_c and y_c, and then traslate it back to the point you want

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard to do +O.

Comment: If not O, what x and y stands for? Are those intersection points?

Comment: generic variables of the Oxy plane ... what would you write if i'd have asked you to tell me the generic circle equation?

Comment: Generic circle equation? Probably X = C.x + r*cos(α), Y = C.y + r*sin(α) being a programmer. :) [Edit: changed the O to C to lower the confusion]

Comment: that's the parametric way to write it :) the way they teach you in high school is x^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0, or (x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=r^2, and that's the form we need in this case

Comment: Yeah, I vaguely remember that :D, OK so they're basically the intersection points, if I get it correctly?

Comment: yea ... the first equation becomes (x-x_o)^2+(y-y_o)^2=r^2 where x_o and y_o are the coordinates of your origin, the rest still stands. basically you intersect the generic circumference with center C and radius r, with the two vectors, you find the intersection point and force the distance between the origin and those points to be equal

Comment: Oh, I get it, let me check it out.

Comment: Wait so x_c in those equation is actually x_o? I'm getting lost :)

Comment: the solution proposed by alnitak is way faster, i suggest you to work on that :) still : C=(x_c,y_c) ; O = (x_o,y_o) that's the notation i've used in every single equation written above. obviously x_c and y_c are unknown while x_o and y_o are not

Comment: I was reacting to you previous comment that have (x-x_o)^2+(y-y_o)^2=r^2, while the answer have (x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2 = r^2.

Comment: @Save actually I've simplified my original answer somewhat

Comment: I don't have strength today to verify whether the solution plausible. So I gave you the benefit of the doubt, and up-ed your answer as well. Thanks.